# using strtok to split one string more than once leads to an unexpected behavior

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

I faced a problem and I need someone to explain what's happening.

I am parsing a string like `a=1&b=2&c=3` and I want to parse it to `["a=1","b=2","c=3"]` and then split each `x=y`.

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f2(char *src)
{
    char *dest = (char *) calloc(strlen(src)+1,sizeof(char));    
   
    strcpy(dest,src); // I copy src to dest to guard src from being messed up with strtok

   // when I comment out the below line, src address doesn't change
   // but why is it changing the src address? I have copied the src to dest!
    char *token = strtok(dest, "="); 
    printf("dest addr: %p token addr: %p \n",dest,token);
}
void f1(char *src)
{
    char *token = strtok(src, "&");
    while (token)
    {
        printf("src addr: %p ", token);
        f2(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, "&");
    }
}
```

And the I run the code like :

```c
TEST(CopyPointer, CopyStrTok)
{
    char str[]="a=1&b=2&c=3";
    f1(str);
}
```

Here is the result:

```
src addr: 0x7ffd4a00ec0c dest addr: 0x558a755d3350 token addr: 0x558a755d3350 // it's fine 
src addr: 0x558a755d3352 dest addr: 0x558a755d3370 token addr: 0x558a755d3370 
//               ^                         ^    
// now src addr is changed and it's pointing to the second character of dest
```

I can't explain why the `src` is manipulated by `f2` while I have copied the `src` to another variable called `dest`?

#### Correction:

As mentioned in one of the answers, `src` address is not changed, just token address is changed!

Comment: that should be `char *dest = calloc(strlen(src) + 1,sizeof(char));` to create room for the NUL terminator. And [no need to cast that result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: When you use `strtok(dest, "=");` inside the function it is no longer associated with `src`, so `token = strtok(NULL, "&");` inside the loop is using `dest` to find the next token.

Comment: If you want to do multiple `strtok()` loops concurrently, you need to use `strtok_r()`.

Comment: Alternatively, have `f2()` use `sscanf()` instead of `strtok()`. Also, `f2()` is leaking memory. Also, odd that you would make `f2()` allocate memory to avoid `strtok()`'s side effect of altering string data, but you wouldn't make `f1()` do the same.

Comment: You could simply use `"&="` as the delimiter string and gather-up 2 _tokens_ at a time...

Comment: @Davood Falahati The provided code does not make sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I just needed an explanation for a behavior. I don't think every example code should necessarily make sense.

Comment: @DavoodFalahati "_I want to parse it to ["a=1","b=2","c=3"] and then split each x=y._" What's the meaning of "_and then..._"? The code you presented does not perform these as separate and sequential steps... Are we supposed to _read_ **your** _mind?_

Comment: Just use `strdup` as you tokenize the string and store the result in an array of pointers.

Comment: @Lundin nice one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strtok` function uses static internal data to keep track of where it is.

So when you call `strtok` in `f1` it is associated with `src` in that function (which is the same as `str` in your test function), but when you call it again in `f2` with `dest` as the first argument, it is now associated with `dest` in `f2`.  Then when you call `strtok` again in `f1` with `NULL` as the first argument, it's using an internal pointer to a member of `dest` which is no longer in scope.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to use multiple levels of `strtok`, you should instead use `strtok_r` which allows the user to pass in an addition parameter to store its state.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void f2(char *src)
{
    char *p = NULL;
    char *token = strtok_r(src, "=", &p);
    printf("token a=%s\n", token);
    token = strtok_r(NULL, "=", &p);
    printf("token b=%s\n", token);
}
void f1(char *src)
{
    char *p = NULL;
    char *token = strtok_r(src, "&", &p);
    while (token)
    {
        f2(token);
        token = strtok_r(NULL, "&", &p);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "a=1&b=2&c=3";
    f1(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
token a=a
token b=1
token a=b
token b=2
token a=c
token b=3
```

Comment: nice explanation, now I got it, the second strtok(NULL,"&") is still referring to dest in f2.

Answer (score 1):

Why make it complicated? The objective is to extract *pairs* of strings:

```
int main( void ) {
    char str[] = "a=1&b=2&c=3";

    char *p1, *p2;
    for( p1 = str; ( p1 = strtok( p1, "&=") ) != NULL; p1 = NULL ) {
        p2 = strtok( NULL, "&=" );

        printf( "%s ... %s\n", p1, p2 );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a ... 1
b ... 2
c ... 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`src` is not changing and you see changes as you do not print `src` only `token` (but in your format string is src instead of token)

Corrected version

```
void f1(char *src)
{
    char *token = strtok(src, "&");
    while (token)
    {
        printf("src addr: %p token addr: %p ", (void *)src, (void*)token);
        f2(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, "&");
    }
}
```